# Using standard deviation of outcome variable as predictor in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, standard-deviation, heteroscedasticity

I am attempting to fit a multiple linear regression equation to a continuous, real-valued outcome variable, $Y$, using a number of predictive variables, $(X_1, X_2, ... X_n)$, i.e.,

$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 ... \beta_n x_n + \varepsilon
$$

One predictive variable under consideration is the standard deviation of the outcome variable, $SD_Y$.

My assumption is that in order for this to have any predictive power, $Y$ would have to be heteroscedastic and thus, no longer a good candidate for OLS linear regression.

My questions:

1. Is this assumption true?
2. If so, what would be good alternatives to OLS linear regression in this scenario?
3. Are there other potential issues here by using $SD_Y$ as a predictor of $Y$ in a regression analysis?

Thank you.